# How can create an empty arrayin python like a C++ array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to create an empty nd-array in python without zeros or ones functions looks like in c++ with this command for array 3*4 for integers:

```
int x[3][4]
```

Please help me

Comment: Why do you say 'without zeros or ones'?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"?  In numpy, usually empty means "one or more of the dimensions has extent 0".  If you really mean it should have dimensions 3x4, then `zeros` or `ones` is the way to go. It would be unusual in numpy to allocate an array without initializing the content—but as I have *just* this second learned from matt's comment, there is a function `empty` that will do it.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty

Comment: because maybe i need to create char array so i need to change the type or maybe 0 was an important number in the array or any thing else.

Comment: Both of those reasons are somewhat incorrect. If 0 is important, than you don't want an array of random values. Even c++ will initialize arrays depending on compiler options. So if you have a special value you should initialize the array to a set of valid values. Also, changing the type seems irrelevant to whether or not it was initialized.

Comment: If you don't like `empty()`,  try `full()`.  That lets you specify the initial value.

Comment: thanks a lot. empty and full is ok for me.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has a function for that. [empty](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty)